# \mathcal and \mathscr output the same thing in my template

Tags: fonts, packages

In my template compiled by XeLaTeX, `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` output the same thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{pmat}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
    $ \mathcal{ABCD}, \mathscr{ABCD} $
\end{document}
```

Then I get this
[image]

What should I do to get a normal output from `\mathcal{ABCD}` like
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: please post the file in a form we can use `! LaTeX Error: File `pmat.sty' not found.`